# Cannot call member function without object but I call the function with an object

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Human
{
private:
    string Name;
    int Age;
    friend class Utility;
public:
    Human(string InputName,int InputAge)
    {
        Name = InputName;
        Age = InputAge;
    }
};
class Utility
{
public:
    void DisplayAge(const Human& Person)
    {
        cout<<Person.Age<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Human FirstMan("Adam",25);
    cout<<"Accessing private member Age via friend class: ";
    Utility::DisplayAge(FirstMan);
}
```

I don't understand..when I call the function I do send an object(FistMan)..why my compiler still says that I call it without object?

Comment: Make it static. Then it will work. `static void DisplayAge(const Human& Person)`. In utility class, all functions are static in most cases :)

Comment: You are not calling the function with an object. The class name is not an object. Create an object first: `Utility myutility;` then call its functions: `myutility.DisplayAge(FirstMan);`.

Comment: Yeah,you are right..thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DisplayAge` in `Utility` is **not** a `static` function. Therefore you need an *instance* of `Uitility` in order to call it.

So, either make the function `static`, or call it via an *anonymous temporary*

```
Utility().DisplayAge(FirstMan);
```

Better still, make `DisplayAge` a member function of `Human`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `static` keyword and then you'll be able to call your function on your class

I edited your code below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Human
{
private:
    string Name;
    int Age;
    friend class Utility;
public:
    Human(string InputName,int InputAge)
    {
        Name = InputName;
        Age = InputAge;
    }
};

class Utility
{
friend class Human;
public:
    Utility() = default;
    static void DisplayAge(const Human& Person)
    {
        cout<<Person.Age<<endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Human FirstMan("Adam",25);
    cout<<"Accessing private member Age via friend class: ";
    Utility::DisplayAge(FirstMan);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use my answer though as it is bad practice in general. Use the one from @Bathsheba

Answer (score 0):

Dön't use a class whenever you want to define functions. Use a namespace:

```
namespace Utility
{
    inline void DisplayAge(const Human& Person)
    {
        cout<<Person.Age<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Human FirstMan("Adam",25);
    cout<<"Accessing private member Age via friend class: ";
    Utility::DisplayAge(FirstMan);
}
```

Comment: `Age` is private and can't be accessed without making more changes.

Comment: But you can't `friend` a namespace; that's important here.